# Render image sequence works for first frame, but not the rest

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, image

I'd like to make an animation where there are water ripples using dynamic paint. I subdivided a plane which I used as a canvas and applied a UV texture to it. I used some UV spheres to create the ripples. This works fine when I view it in the 3D viewport. When I render the image sequence, the first image looks how I expect it to be, but the rest doesn't. I used the cycles engine. I've tried tweaking the post processing by turning compositing off.

[image: 3D Viewport]
3D Viewport

[image: First frame of render]

First frame of render

[image: Second frame of render]

Second frame of render

I then tried applying the dynamic paint modifier. Now I can see the ripples, but there's no difference in  the ripples between the first and second frame of the render.

[image]

First frame of render with dynamic paint modifier applied

[image]

Second frame of render with dynamic paint modifier applied

This is the [blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/43f85b28034b4f268e6192bd3e5a595e) and this is the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHYyk.jpg) I applied to the texture

What did I do wrong?